# showing file not found exception even i configure the spring configuration file at servlet class level in web.xml

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat

> I tried with so many possibilities but non of them worked for me. I
>   have a spring mvc application with maven and eclipse as build tool. In
>   my application i configure the Context Load listener and Dispatcher
>   servlet inside the dispatcher servlet i configure my spring
>   configuration file but it showing file not found exception of
>   WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml. But i don't have any
>   applicationContext.xml file in my application.I need both
>   ContextLoadListener and dispatcher servlet.How to solve this problem.
>   Here is my Web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
<listener>
   <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
   </listener-class>
</listener> 
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>sdnext</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
     <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
       <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/servlet-context.xml</param-value>  
                    <!-- <param-value>classpath:servlet-context.xml</param-value> -->
        </init-param>    
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>sdnext</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>indexNew.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

And the error which i am getting when i run the url is  http://localhost:8080/sdnext/
and the out put i am getting is error page 404 saying "Request resource not available(/sdnext/)

and in the console i am getting error as

```
Dec 28, 2015 2:14:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\PROGRAM FILES\DELL\DW WLAN CARD;C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\INTEL\ICLS CLIENT\;C:\PROGRAM FILES\INTEL\ICLS CLIENT\;;C:\Windows\SYSTEM32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WBEM;C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINDOWSPOWERSHELL\V1.0\;C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\INTEL\OPENCL SDK\2.0\BIN\X86;C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\INTEL\OPENCL SDK\2.0\BIN\X64;C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\INTEL\OPENCL SDK\2.0\BIN\X86;C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\INTEL\OPENCL SDK\2.0\BIN\X64;;C:\PROGRAM FILES\INTEL\INTEL(R) MANAGEMENT ENGINE COMPONENTS\DAL;C:\PROGRAM FILES\INTEL\INTEL(R) MANAGEMENT ENGINE COMPONENTS\IPT;C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\INTEL\INTEL(R) MANAGEMENT ENGINE COMPONENTS\DAL;C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\INTEL\INTEL(R) MANAGEMENT ENGINE COMPONENTS\IPT;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;;.
Dec 28, 2015 2:14:06 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Spring3HibernateApp' did not find a matching property.
Dec 28, 2015 2:14:06 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Dec 28, 2015 2:14:06 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Dec 28, 2015 2:14:06 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 658 ms
Dec 28, 2015 2:14:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Dec 28, 2015 2:14:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.27
Dec 28, 2015 2:14:07 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [121] milliseconds.
Dec 28, 2015 2:14:07 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Users\zkatwal\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\Spring3HibernateApp\WEB-INF\lib\javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Dec 28, 2015 2:14:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Dec 28, 2015 2:14:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:344)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:605)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:509)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5273)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1566)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1556)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:141)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:330)
    ... 21 more

Dec 28, 2015 2:14:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Dec 28, 2015 2:14:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/sdnext] startup failed due to previous errors
Dec 28, 2015 2:14:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Dec 28, 2015 2:14:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStop
SEVERE: Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.getBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:170)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1000)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:976)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:928)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:583)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4819)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5466)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1566)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1556)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Dec 28, 2015 2:14:08 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Dec 28, 2015 2:14:08 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Dec 28, 2015 2:14:08 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1432 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

--- Edited ---
After a long chat discussion, the problem was identified in the setup of the maven project. It was not following the standard maven project directory structure. The xml file was not being copied in the expected target location and could not be loaded by the context loader.

Comment: Thanks for the replay but when i changed the code as per your suggestion it showing this error now :Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/servlet-context.xml]

Comment: Where is your servlet-context.xml? In your original post the path is: /WEB-INF/config/servlet-context.xml not /WEB-INF/servlet-context.xml

Comment: My Application Structure is : MyApplication-->WebRoot-->WEB-INF-->Config--->Servlet-Context.xml   this is my project structre

Comment: In your context-param entry, did you put the path: /WEB-INF/config/servlet-context.xml or /WEB-INF/servlet-context.xml

Comment: I used both the ways first time i tried by putting /WEB-INF/config/serlvet-context.xml  after that i kept the servlet-context.xml file directly inside the WEB-INF this time it is showing "java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/sdnext-servlet.xml]"

Comment: I think you have been doing way too much try-and-error and now have a mess of files and names... Just make sure that the path you specify in your web.xml with the contextConfigLocation parameter is exactly the same as in your file system (including upper and lower case). The error message says that it is looking for a file named sdnext-servlet.xml within the WEB-INF directory...

Comment: Every thing is fine, I check one more time but it seems every thing correctly i am using but still the same issue."Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/sdnext-servlet.xml]"

Comment: Well if the file is really there, read permissions are available and the spelling of the name is correct, then my last suggestion is that you try to use an empty application context file to ensure that the error is not caused by a parsing issue (which should not be the case being a FileNotFoundException)... I'll give up on other attempts to help, sorry

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99111/discussion-between-zameer-and-danilo-tommasina).

Comment: So could you post the fixed pom.xml with correct directory structure?